# Вставить изображение внутри тега таблицы (<td>) в MD

Tags: github, документация, markdown

Пытаюсь вставить изображение с относительным путём в *.md файл на github'е.

```
![public](media/pubclass.gif)
```

Когда просто вставляю сразу после заголовка, то всё нормально отображается. 
Но стоит вставить строчку выше между тегами `<td></td>` и уже не отображается почему-то =/

```
![public](media/pubclass.gif)
<table>
    <tr>
        <th/>
        <th>Класс</th>
        <th>Описание</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> ![public](media/pubclass.gif) </td>
        <td>
            <a target="_blank" href="T_ShikiApiLib_ShikiApi.md">ShikiApi</a>
        </td>
        <td>Инициализированный экземпляр данного класса означает авторизованного пользователя</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>![public](media/pubclass.gif)</td>
        <td>
            <a target="_blank" href="T_ShikiApiLib_ShikiApiStatic.md">ShikiApiStatic</a>
        </td>
        <td>Статический класс, содержаший в себе методы, не требующие авторизации</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно вставить изображение в ячейку таблицы? 
По разному пробовал. И полный путь и относительный. И с raw и без него =/

Comment: Раз Вы решили таблицу делать в html, то и картику вставляйте также.

Comment: @KoVadim, а так можно? о_0 текст не я писал, он сгенерированный в софтине для генерации XML документации в MD.

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо, помогло.. кстати, не подскажите как вылечить уменьшение размера иконок в ячейке таблицы, если в той же строчке в другой ячейке многострочный текст?

Comment: новый вопрос - кнопка "задать вопрос".

Comment: @KoVadim http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/644621/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc