# Как исправить уменьшение иконок в таблице с многострочным текстом?

Tags: github, markdown

Как исправить уменьшение иконок в MD в таблице с многострочным текстом?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th/>
        <th>Имя</th>
        <th>Описание</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="media/pubmethod.gif" /></td>
        <td>
            <a target="_blank" href="M_ShikiApiLib_ShikiApi__ctor.md">ShikiApi(String, String)</a>
        </td>
        <td>Инициализирует нового пользователя, запрашивая токен и ID пользователя с сайта.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="media/pubmethod.gif" /></td>
        <td>
            <a target="_blank" href="M_ShikiApiLib_ShikiApi__ctor_1.md">ShikiApi(String, String, Int32)</a>
        </td>
        <td>Инициализирует нового пользователя, явно задавая значения токена и ID пользователя.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: думается мне, что там картинки разного размера.

Comment: @KoVadim Нет. Эта же картинка в другой таблице (где текст в одну строку) с нормальным размером